# Rotate individual letters of the text using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, characters

I would like to rotate each character in the text of the TikZ edge label while keeping the edge label's orientation unchanged.

The following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

% TikZ styles
\tikzset{
root/.style={circle,draw=red!70,fill=red!30},
leaf/.style={circle,draw=blue!70,fill=blue!30},
label/.style={sloped,above}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [root] {$r$}
    child { node [leaf] {$l_1$}
        edge from parent
        node[label] {\texttt{CBA}}
    }
    child { node [leaf] {$l_2$}
        edge from parent
        node[label] {\texttt{ABC}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces this:

[image: characters not rotated]

The text is sloped according to the edge orientation, which is great. However, what I would like to achieve is to keep the baseline of the text sloped while rotating each of the characters individually. I would also like to adjust the character spacing if necessary.

The effect which I would like to achieve is to make each character look like it has not been rotated at all while changing the orientation of the text as a whole. The result should look like this:

[image: characters rotated]

Is there any way to achieve that?
I know that I can put some nodes containing the individual letters along the edge's path, but I was wondering if there is a simpler method.

Ideally, I would prefer to have some sort of style, say `slopedandrotated`, which would do exactly that.

Comment: Vaguely related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28982/86

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `text along path` decoration can be altered slightly to set the indivdual characters upright. This solution requires a bit of manual adjustment using `raise` and `text align/left indent` to get the positioning right, but it works quite well. It supports all the options of the original `text along path` decoration, as described in the manual. To use text formatting options, you have to enclose them in delimiters, which default to `|`. I've added an option to increase the spacing between the individual letters, called `kern factor`, as some font options don't look good with the default spacing.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

% TikZ styles
\tikzset{
root/.style={circle,draw=red!70,fill=red!30},
leaf/.style={circle,draw=blue!70,fill=blue!30},
label/.style={sloped,above}
}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    /pgf/decoration/kern factor/.code=\pgfmathsetmacro\tikz@textalongpath@kern{0.5*#1},
    /pgf/decoration/kern factor=1
}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{text along path not sloped}{initial}{
\state{initial}[width=+0pt, next state=left indent, 
    persistent precomputation={%
        \edef\pgf@lib@dec@text@indent@left{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/text align/left indent}}%
        \edef\pgf@lib@dec@text@indent@right{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/text align/right indent}}%
        \edef\pgf@lib@dec@text@align{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/text align/align}}%
        \pgfdecoratedremainingdistance=\pgfdecoratedpathlength%
      \advance\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance by-\pgf@lib@dec@text@indent@right\relax%
      \edef\pgfdecoratedpathlength{\the\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance}%
      \pgf@lib@dec@text@getwidth%
      \pgf@x=\pgf@lib@dec@text@width\relax%
      \pgf@y=\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance%
      \ifpgf@lib@dec@text@fit%
        \advance\pgf@y by-\pgf@lib@dec@text@indent@left\relax%
        \advance\pgf@y by-\pgf@x%
        \ifpgf@lib@dec@text@stretch@spaces%
            \def\pgf@lib@dec@text@character@shift{0pt}%
            \divide\pgf@y by\pgf@lib@dec@space@count\relax%
            \edef\pgf@lib@dec@text@space@shift{\the\pgf@y}%
        \else%
            \c@pgf@counta=\pgf@lib@dec@character@count\relax%
            \advance\c@pgf@counta by-1\relax%
            \divide\pgf@y by\c@pgf@counta\relax%
            \edef\pgf@lib@dec@text@character@shift{\the\pgf@y}%
            \def\pgf@lib@dec@text@space@shift{0pt}%
          \fi%
          \ifdim\pgf@y<0pt\relax%
            \pgf@lib@dec@text@fitfalse%
            \pgf@lib@dec@text@stretch@spacesfalse%
            \def\pgf@lib@dec@text@character@shift{0pt}%
            \def\pgf@lib@dec@text@space@shift{0pt}%
          \fi%
      \else%
        \def\pgf@lib@dec@text@character@shift{0pt}%
        \def\pgf@lib@dec@text@space@shift{0pt}%
          \ifx\pgf@lib@dec@text@align\pgf@lib@dec@text@left@text%
          \else%
            \ifx\pgf@lib@dec@text@align\pgf@lib@dec@text@right@text%
                \advance\pgf@y by-\pgf@x%
                \edef\pgf@lib@dec@text@indent@left{\the\pgf@y}%
            \else%
                \advance\pgf@y by-\pgf@x%
                \advance\pgf@y by-\pgf@lib@dec@text@indent@left\relax%
                \pgf@y=0.5\pgf@y%
                \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@lib@dec@text@indent@left\relax%
                \edef\pgf@lib@dec@text@indent@left{\the\pgf@y}%
            \fi%
          \fi%
      \fi%
      \let\pgfdecorationrestoftext=\pgfdecorationtext%
    }]{}
\state{left indent}[width=+\pgf@lib@dec@text@indent@left, next state=scan]{}
%
\state{scan}[width=+0pt, next state=before typeset,
 persistent precomputation={
   \pgf@lib@dec@text@scanchar%
   \ifvoid\pgf@lib@dec@text@box%
     \setbox\pgf@lib@dec@text@box\hbox{}%
     \wd\pgf@lib@dec@text@box16383pt\relax%
   \fi%
 }]{}
%
\state{before typeset}[width=+\tikz@textalongpath@kern\wd\pgf@lib@dec@text@box, next state=typeset]{}
%
\state{typeset}[width=+0pt, next state=after typeset]
{%
  \pgftransformresetnontranslations
  \setbox\pgf@hbox\hbox{\copy\pgf@lib@dec@text@box}%
  \pgfqboxsynced\pgf@hbox%
}
\state{after typeset}[width=+.5\wd\pgf@lib@dec@text@box, next state=shift,
    persistent precomputation={%
    \ifpgf@lib@dec@text@fit%
        \ifpgf@lib@dec@text@stretch@spaces%
            \ifpgf@lib@dec@text@scan@space%
                \let\pgf@lib@dec@text@shift=\pgf@lib@dec@text@space@shift%
            \else%
                \def\pgf@lib@dec@text@shift{0pt}%
            \fi%
        \else%
            \let\pgf@lib@dec@text@shift=\pgf@lib@dec@text@character@shift%
          \fi%
        \else%
            \def\pgf@lib@dec@text@shift{0pt}%
      \fi%  
  }]{}
\state{shift}[width=+\pgf@lib@dec@text@shift, next state=scan]{}
\state{final}{}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [root] {$r$}
    child { node [leaf] {$l_1$}
        edge from parent[postaction={
            decorate,
            decoration={
                text along path not sloped,
                raise=-1.75ex,
                text={|\ttfamily|CBA},
                text align/left indent=0.5em,
                kern factor=2
            }
        }]
    }
    child { node [leaf] {$l_2$}
        edge from parent [postaction={
            decorate,
            decoration={
                text along path not sloped,
                raise=0.4ex,
                text={|\ttfamily|ABC},
                text align/left indent=0.3em,
                kern factor=2
            }
        }]
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, what a fast response! Thank you very much! It really appears to be working. I don't understand the code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, but it appears to do the job. Despite not being perfect and fully automatic, I accept it.

Comment: I have created this 3-parameter style to make it a little bit more usable:

`edge not sloped/.style n args={3}{postaction={
        decorate,
        decoration={
        text along path not sloped,
        raise=#2,
        text={#1},
        text align/left indent=#3
        }
    }}`

Comment: Normally, `@` is a special character that can't be used in command names.  `\makeatletter` temporarily changes its category code to "letter", so that it can be used.  `\makeatother` changes it back.  This convention lets package authors define "internal" macros that cannot be called inadvertently from the main document.  As for fully-automatic -- no solution can work fully with all possible fonts; ultimately, tweaking the design to look right is best left to the designer's eye.

Comment: However, there is still one more issue: I can't seem to figure out how to change the text font, shape, size, color etc. Simply putting `\texttt{ABC}` in place of the text does not work (latex freezes - it probably gets into some infinite loop). I hope it can be achieved easily.

Comment: @PeterBašista: Adding font formatting options is a bit different to normal in this case, it works as it does for the normal `text along path` decoration as described in the manual. I've edited my answer to show an example.

Comment: @Jake: Thank you for an update! It seems to work great!