# Put text in any shapes with automatic line breaking in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I notice that we can put text in a circle by

`\node[draw,circle]{Text};`

Is it possible to put text in any shapes with automatic line breaking? (e.g., in an ellipse, or in a closed curve that we draw)

**EDIT**

For the demand of "putting text in any closed curve we draw" is probably a duplicate of [Fitting text to a shape in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67032/fitting-text-to-a-shape-in-tikz) (`\shapeparnode` is used), though I'm looking forward to a shape option of `\node` that uses a closed curve we draw.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sure. SImply use `text width` with/without `align`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,fill=cyan!30,ellipse,text width=2cm] 
  {Some text goes here inside this ellipse};
\node[xshift=4cm,draw,fill=green!25,ellipse,text width=2cm,align=center] 
  {Some text goes here inside this ellipse};
\node[xshift=8cm,draw,fill=yellow!25,ellipse,text width=2cm,align=right] 
  {Some text goes here inside this ellipse};
\node[xshift=2cm,yshift=-3cm,draw,fill=orange!25,trapezium,text width=2cm,align=center] 
  {Some text goes here inside this trapezium};
\node[yshift=-3cm,xshift=6cm,draw,fill=magenta!25,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,text width=2cm,align=center] 
  {Some text goes here inside this hexagon};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Regarding the part about putting text in any closed curve we draw, there might be a number of possible approaches here:

- The `\shapeparnode` command defined by **Paul Gaborit** in [`his answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68740/3954) to [Fitting text to a shape in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67032/3954).
- Defining a new shape as described in Section **75.5 Declaring New Shapes** of the PGF manual (this is a non trivial process, which might be simplified by the using the package in the following item).
- Using the [`makeshape`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/makeshape) package to simplify the creation of new shapes. This is the abstract from the package documentation:

> The makeshape package simplifies writing PGF shapes. Declaring a
>   custom shape with a correct anchor border can be difficult. Complex
>   shapes often need complicated calculations to find the touching point
>   of a connecting line. This package only requires that a developer
>   write a PGF path describing the anchor border. It also provides macros
>   that help with the management of shape parameters and the definition
>   of anchor points.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What if we can to put some text in a closed curve that we draw rather than predefined shapes, Is it possible to define a "text region" by drawing a closed curve, and give it a name as ```myTextRegion```? Finally we use it as ```\node[draw,myTextRegion, text width=2cm]{some text};``` ? (or maybe without option ```text width```, just let it fit ```myTextRegion``` automatically)

Comment: @Hongying I've added to my answer some possible approaches to deal with the "arbitrary closed curve".