# Drawing nonuniform bubble

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw a nonuniform text bubble and fitting the text inside of it.

[image: JW4Ot.jp]

Comment: hi ! show us a MWE ; And maybe `tikz` could help you

Comment: @GuilhermeZanotelli this solves the second part only of my question, thanks.

Comment: @AhmedHawary, second part? What's the first?

Comment: @GuilhermeZanotelli 1-Drawing a non-uniform bubble. 2- Fitting the text. Sorry if the questions is not clear enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a bubble:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw  plot [smooth,tension=1.3] coordinates {(1.cm+rand*.1cm,.2cm+rand*.1cm) (0cm+rand*0cm,-1cm+rand*.1cm) (-1cm+rand*0.1cm,0cm+rand*0.1cm) (0cm+rand*0.1cm,1cm+rand*0.1cm) (1.cm+rand*.1cm,-.2cm+rand*.1cm)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: bubble]

You can always hard-code the coordinates instead of the random ones I've used.

Putting text inside it is [quite simple](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109679/28808)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw  plot [smooth,tension=1.3] coordinates {(1.cm+rand*.1cm,.2cm+rand*.1cm) (0cm+rand*0cm,-1cm+rand*.1cm) (-1cm+rand*0.1cm,0cm+rand*0.1cm) (0cm+rand*0.1cm,1cm+rand*0.1cm) (1.cm+rand*.1cm,-.2cm+rand*.1cm)};
    \node[text width=1.4cm] at(0,0) {\small{This is some text in a bubble}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: bubble with text]

Here it's a bit nicer to use:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,intersections}
\newcommand\bubblenodetext[3]{\node [draw=none, shape=circle, text width=0cm, inner sep=5mm] at (#1,#2) (bubblenode){\shapepar{\circleshape} #3\par};
    \def\startendoffset{3mm}
    \draw  plot [smooth,tension=1.3] coordinates {($(bubblenode.east)+(\startendoffset,\startendoffset)$) (bubblenode.south) (bubblenode.west) (bubblenode.north) ($(bubblenode.east)+(\startendoffset,-\startendoffset)$)};
}
%change draw=none to draw=red to see the line bounding the text. 
\newcommand\randombubblenodetext[3]{\node [draw=none, shape=circle, text width=0cm, inner sep=2mm] at (#1,#2) (bubblenode){\shapepar{\circleshape} #3\par};
    \def\startendoffset{3mm}
    \def\randomfactor{3mm}
    \draw  plot [smooth,tension=1.3] coordinates {($(bubblenode.east)+(\startendoffset+rnd*\randomfactor,\startendoffset+rand*\randomfactor)$)
        ($(bubblenode.south)+(rand*\randomfactor,-rnd*\randomfactor)$) 
        ($(bubblenode.west)+(-rnd*\randomfactor,rand*\randomfactor)$) 
        ($(bubblenode.north)+(rand*\randomfactor,rnd*\randomfactor)$) 
        ($(bubblenode.east)+(\startendoffset+rnd*\randomfactor,-\startendoffset+rand*\randomfactor)$)};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \bubblenodetext {0}{0}{Now we automate the bubble.  We can still fill it with text.}
    \randombubblenodetext{5}{0}{This is a slightly random bubble.  We can still fill it with text.}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: automagic bubbles]

In the right-hand example I've also reduce the inner sep -- you need to strike a balance here as the text doesn't really respond to the shape I've drawn, but to a circle (see comment on line 10).  The code was shamelessly stolen from [Count Zero's answer to *Fitting text to a shape in TikZ*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68678/28808).

Things to tweak to get the look you're going for: `inner sep` `tension`, `\startendoffset`, `\randomfactor` (which you may want to set to 0).

Comment: You'd probably like a little more automation that that if you're going to use it a lot.  I've got an idea

Comment: It might be nice to try to combine with some of the suggestions at [Simulating hand-drawn lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39296/28808)

Comment: It works nicely with the shaky [pathmorphing solution from @user10274](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39299/28808)