# How to shape text like any english capital alphabet

Tags: xetex

I want to write a letter which should be shaped as 'I', 'U', 'T', 'H', 'N', 'A'.

For example refer to the below image:

[image: T shaped text]

I am actually in search of simpler method, like any package that have function of formatting texts in the shape of any English alphabet, as I am new to tex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fitting text to a shape in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67032/fitting-text-to-a-shape-in-tikz)

Comment: I'm not sure about the duplicate -- in particular adapting it for "A" using the accepted solution there would be non-trivial.  I looked into it recently for [Drawing nonuniform bubble](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347957/drawing-nonuniform-bubble/347982#347982)  before taking a different approach. (@ebo)

Comment: I am actually in search of simpler method like any package that have function of formatting text in any English alphabet as I am new to tex

Comment: Leave Open.  It is the issue of A, B, D, etc with enclosed non-text regions, and G, H, K, etc with disjoint horizontal text which makes this a very different question.   Would eventually make a very nice package.

Comment: @SakilAlam: Yes, everyone wants something simple... that's not the case with your request.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Text wrap with `shapepar` (insert image between text)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34546/5764)