# Centering with increasing width

Tags: horizontal-alignment

Is there a way to make text centered with increasing width? 
[image: example]

Comment: You may find the answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109674/put-text-in-any-shapes-with-automatic-line-breaking-in-tikz

Comment: Use of `\centering` with manual breakpoints would allow this: `\centering
the quick\\
brown fox jumps\\
over the lazy dog\par`.  But if you want the breaks to occur automatically according to some prespecified row-width growth formula, you probably need `\parshape` (see, for example, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148883/non-rectangular-body-geometry).