# If one has package-related documentation notes, where are those posted?

Tags: documentation, ctan

Since they'd be something other than just MWE code examples, are those posted here or, say, on CTAN?

Comment: Yes.  Notes on the package documentation found in exactly that type of CTAN page.

Comment: Thanks for having a minute.  What if my contribution to the mix is directed toward that package documentation, itself? In other words, if there's something "new" or "different" to add regarding package documentation, where would that "something new" be posted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I have made this into an answer as it would be to long otherwise and deleted my comments on the question.*

I guess you are referring to information like https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf.

If a package is distributed by the three distributions `TeX Live`, `MacTeX`, and `proTeXt`, then you usually find the documentation on CTAN and the distribution itself (i.e you have a copy of the files on your hard drive). These three distributions cover the most important operating systems and I recommend using one of these. Naturally, you will not find information on "external" packages. As *@Skillmon* has pointed out, CTAN "is only" the host and the package/class authors "have" to provide information on themselves.

I am certainly not an expert as I have never uploaded anything. Others probably could contribute more. You should find basic information on https://ctan.org/file/help/ctan/CTAN-upload-addendum. If you think you have anything worth contributing I would publish it on CTAN which imho is the standard source. CTAN also features documents which are not classical documentations of packages or classes like https://ctan.org/pkg/happy4th and https://ctan.org/pkg/lshort-english.

There are some entries like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68740/128553 on this site which I would wish to be packages on ctan, but they are not. You can also post a topic on this site and upload your solution as an answer on this site to share it with the world. Needless to say, that there are other community pages like http://www.texample.net which offer good solutions, not all of those community pages are in English.

I would like to add another perspective on one of Skillmon's comments below. We do not know the number of people who do read the manual and find solutions to their problems by themselves, thus simple questions on this site might give the impression that many people do not read the manuals. On the other hand, users might not find what they looking for because the do not exactly know what to look for or where to look for. If you do not know the name of the concept you are looking for, you might not be able to find the fitting packages or the the relevant two sentences in a large documentation.

Writing good on complex software documentation for alle stakeholders is a difficult task and comes with various problems which apply to non-`TeX`-related software, too.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks.  (I tried to vote this up, but I'll come back and do that as that's possible to do.)  Yes, there are such excellent answers and insight in this forum that having this "communications tool" available is invaluable, for all levels of \LaTeX typesetters. Some of these threads should be made part of the package documentation.  As I get that set of notes together, I'll contact the folks with CTAN.

Comment: @SapharKoshet note that CTAN is not responsible for package documentations or their contents, that lies in the reliability of the package authors/maintainers.

Comment: Very good to know. So, they post the information, and would likely also post some documentation focused notes, I'm learning.

Comment: @SapharKoshet as a package author you upload the following things to CTAN: The sources for the package, the sources for the documentation, a readme, and the documentation. The first two in this list might be in the same file (take a look at *.dtx files). There might be packages for which you upload more files than that, but for a small package that's about it. (Note that you don't upload the built package if you upload a *.dtx)

Comment: Excellent. My focus at the moment is simply on "translating" "design engineer" documentation into "production engineer" documentation.  While there are, say, "grad level" exchanges in this forum, there are a high percentage of \LaTeX 101 and 201 questions, and while time-pressure will spawn questions, because the support beyond just the techno question is needed to get through the time pressure, some of what is asked/answered might be possible to address via the documentation, if it were more "production engineer" oriented.

Comment: @SapharKoshet my personal experience is that most users don't read the documentation. There are often questions on this very site in which questioners ask stuff which is clearly stated in the documentation. The first questions I answered were often of the type "I'll find that thingy in the documentation faster than the others". But it is correct that one tends to write documentation harder to understand for the total beginner the more one has expertise.

Comment: @Skillmon :) :) :) Yes.  I hear what you're saying, and I just can't help but wonder how much of the documentation the newbies (such as myself) would otherwise read they don't read because it's more "design engineer" oriented than "production engineer" oriented.  Some of it is, shall we say, "difficult" to read. Between you, me, and this electronic fencepost, I expect that's something that has a remedy.

Comment: @SapharKoshet The main problem with writing package documentation is that every single command and option has to be described. For a large package, this is often too much information for a beginner, but advanced users get miffed if a useful feature isn't documented. It's sometimes not possible to write a comprehensive user manual that's pitched satisfactorily at both levels (which is why I added introductory guides to accompany [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) and [`bib2gls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls) but I'm not sure how many people read them).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I can only imagine! And, yes, how much of what is provided is actually read is a huge question. The "design"-oriented documentation can be, shall we say, burdensome, or overwhelming. What this forum provides is "how to," and something in the way of links from the official documentation to the reality of the matter I think would save a lot of time, not to mention frustration. E.g., how much time is "invested" addressing matters of "known" incompatibility or solved by a "simple" load sequence solution? Info not normally found in the "design" documentation.

Comment: @SapharKoshet well the aim is to write documentation for one's package, not to document the other packages. There are a few packages which do have such compatibility sections, though. And every package which wants to be loaded after `hyperref` should state that, imho (`hyperref` is one of the packages most frequently loaded at the wrong spot).