# tikz: fit text exactly into the node (trapezium shape)

Tags: tikz-node, tikz-shape

This LaTeX source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[trapezium, draw, trapezium left angle=120, trapezium right angle=90,text width=8cm] (labelTransform) at (0,0) {Very long and interesting description of sometfing. We also add some more text and also symbols like $\tau$, $\phi$ or $\aleph$ to look exceptionaly scientific. Moreover, this way we make the text even longer.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives this output

[image]

Is there possibility to make the node to look like this:

[image]

Thanks for help!

**EDIT**: Thanks to Ivan's response I got actually this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\newcommand{\trapeziumParShape}{
{-2}
{0}b{-2}\\ 
{0}t{-2}{19}\\ 
{5}t{2.5}{14.5}\\ 
{5}e{2.5}
}

  \node[trapezium, draw, trapezium left angle=120, trapezium right angle=90] at (0,0) {
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \Shapepar{\trapeziumParShape}Very long and interesting description of sometfing. We also add some more text and also symbols like $\tau$, $\phi$ or $\aleph$ to look exceptionaly scientific. Moreover, this way we make the text even longer.
   \end{minipage}
   }; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces this:

[image]

and no idea how to shift the text inside the node to the proper place.

Comment: This may help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67032/fitting-text-to-a-shape-in-tikz. I modified your code to make it an MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/231952)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*SEE LATER FOR SHAPEPAR APPROACH*

This is a hack, and therefore not encouraged.  What I do is use `tabstackengine` to set the text (even though I have no tabbing).  The downside is that manual line breaks are required here.  Thus, the lines will also be ragged.

So what is the hack?  I left align the stack (`\tabbedCenterstack[l]` ) and employ the `\TABstackTextstyle` feature to apply a macro to each cell (it is not intended to take an argument, but to specify shape, fontsize, etc. for each cell).  However, the macro I employ is `\traptab` that reads two arguments!

It regurgitates them (so nothing is lost), but uses `#2` as part of an `\hspace` argument.  This is because I know (having written the package) that the first thing that `\TABstackTextstyle` will find is a special strut command with an argument corresponding to the row number (the strut is used to set either row baselineskip or gap between rows).  Thus, what `traptab` does is subtract off a space corresponding to the total number of rows minus the current row number (In this example, `#2` will vary from `1` to `4`, and `\TABstack@rows` will always be 4).

I set `\thetraptab` to 8pt, so that the first row gets 24pts left shift, then 16pt for the 2nd row, 8pt for the 3rd row and 0pt for the 4th row.

Yuck!  But here it is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\def\thetraptab{8pt}
\makeatletter
\def\traptab#1#2{#1{#2}\hspace{\numexpr#2-\TABstack@rows\relax
  \dimexpr\thetraptab\relax}}
\makeatother
\TABstackTextstyle{\traptab}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[trapezium, draw, trapezium left angle=120, trapezium right angle=90,text width=8cm] (labelTransform) at (0,0) {%
  \tabbedCenterstack[l]{%
  Very long and interesting description of something. We\\% <- MANUAL BREAKS 
  also add some more text and also symbols like $\tau$, $\phi$, or\\ 
  $\aleph$ to look exceptionaly scientific. Moreover, this way\\ 
  we make the text even longer.%
}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**SHAPEPAR*

I have no proficiency at shapepar...but,

Using the OP's code, I did several changes: I changed the width of the `minipage` to `2.8in` and I added an `\hspace{-24pt}` prior to the `\Shapepar`.  I also twiddled the shapepar parameters to achieve a 4 line stack.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\newcommand{\trapeziumParShape}{
{-2}
{0}b{-3}\\ 
{0}t{-3}{18}\\ 
{4}t{0}{15}\\ 
{4}e{0}
}

  \node[trapezium, draw, trapezium left angle=120, trapezium right angle=90] at (0,0) {
  \begin{minipage}{2.8in}
        \hspace{-24pt}%
        \Shapepar{\trapeziumParShape}Very long and interesting description of sometfing. We also add some more text and also symbols like $\tau$, $\phi$ or $\aleph$ to look exceptionaly scientific. Moreover, this way we make the text even longer.
   \end{minipage}
   }; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Steven for the shapepar approach! Works well!