# Using maya numerals as enumerate labels

Tags: enumerate, mathabx

I am trying to redefine the enumerate labels so I can use maya numerals (`\mayadigit` from the mathabx package, or ideally the fixed rotated ones from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142257/horizontal-maya-numerals-mathabx)). I tried simply doing `\renewcommand\theenumi{\mayadigit{enumi}}` as you would do with `\roman`. In this case I get the following error:

> Missing number, treated as zero

It seems that `\roman` has more structure than `\mayadigit`. but I cannot find what I need to define the same thing for `\mayadigit`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Maybe with `\mayadigit{\value{enumi}]`?

Comment: Well, that seems to fix the problem. I still get a dot afterwards which I would want to get rid of. Thanks a lot @Bernard

Comment: I've taken a look at the documentation of mathbax. As I understand it, the command should be `\maya{...}`. To remove the final dot, try using `enumitem` (something like [label=\maya{enumi}].

Comment: The thing with `\maya{}` is that it adds a box, which I don't like. The downside of `\mayadigit{}` is that it stops being correct at 21. On the other hand, while `\maya{}` is correct it becomes unwieldy due to the nature of the ordering (symbols stacked vertically).

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make this work using `enumitem` by looking at the `moreenum` package. Here is my solution, in case anyone is interested:

```latex
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\newcommand\mathbfont{\usefont{U}{mathb}{m}{n}}

\def\mayaexpansion{%
    \mayacntc=\mayacnta\mathbfont
    \ifnum\mayacntc=0 0\else
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{%
    \loop\ifnum\mayacntc>5\advance\mayacntc by -5\repeat
    \the\mayacntc\mayacntc=\mayacnta
    \loop\ifnum\mayacntc>5\advance\mayacntc by -5 5\repeat}%
    \fi}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mayalabel}[1]{%
  \expandafter\@mayalabel\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand*{\@mayalabel}[1]{%
  \protect\mayadigit{\number#1}}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\mayalabel}{\@mayalabel}{\mayadigit{5}}
\makeatother 

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mayafull}[1]{%
  \expandafter\@mayafull\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand*{\@mayafull}[1]{%
  \protect\ensuremath{\maya{\number#1}}}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\mayafull}{\@mayafull}{\maya{5}}
\makeatother
```

Using `[label=\mayalabel*]` gives you `\mayadigit{}` while `[label=\mayafull*]` gives you `\maya{}`. None of them really work beyond twenty though. The former is wrong and the latter is bulky.