# How to typeset inverted characters in ExLaTex on Mac OSX

Tags: typography, rotating, mac

How do you represent a text that contains printers' pie: specifically letters the are upside down? I am using ExLaTex and attempting to reproduce 19th century newspaper articles faithfully: including type-setting errors such as inverted 'g' and inverted 'e'.

Comment: Consider providing a minimal working example (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for us to copy to our files and try.  Also, please tell us what you've tried and how it's failed you.  Finally, welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: some methods of turning characters/text upside down are shown in answers to this question: [Text upside-down, characters rotated along baseline?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28861/579)

Comment: dgoodmaniii, Thank you for your advice and helpful comments.

Answer (score 4):

If you absolutely need to do it by rotating characters to get that old-timey feel, the easiest way is probably to use the `graphicx` package's convenient commands, `\rotatebox` and `\reflectbox`.  Because it's not clear to me whether you want rotated, reflected, or both, I do all three below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\rotatee{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{e}}
\def\rotateg{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{g}}
\def\inverte{\reflectbox{e}}
\def\invertg{\reflectbox{g}}
\def\rotinve{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\reflectbox{e}}}
\def\rotinvg{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\reflectbox{g}}}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
This is sp\rotatee{}ll\rotatee{}d wron\rotateg.

This is sp\inverte{}ll\inverte{}d wron\invertg.

This is sp\rotinve{}ll\rotinve{}d wron\rotinvg.
\end{document}
```

That gives you this:

[image: Rotated, inverted, and both.]

Some of these already exist, however; for example, schwa is a common character, which is a rotated "e".  You'd almost certainly be better off using those where they exist.

Comment: dgoodmaniii, The code worked just as I needed it to. Many thanks. Marz